# Refreshing QGIS layers panel after update in python

Tags: qgis, python

**How can I refresh the *Layers Panel* in QGIS through python?**

In my code I have loop and within line to update visibility of some layer in the legend:

```
self.iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible( layer, True )
```

At the beginning I thought it should do that that automatically. But it doesn't. Very interesting thing for me is that if I have open Python Console and print something after that line the *Layers Panel* gets updated. If the Python Console is closed nothing happens.

My intention is to build plugin witch **loop through layers in selected group and for every layer turns it on (the rest in group turn off) and export composer**. The whole problem is that after switching visibility of layers the **Layers Panel won't update automatically** and so also the composer is not updated and gets exported without any change in the layers visibility. Just accidentally I have found out that if I open Python Console and with every loop print out something not only Python Console gets updated but for some reason also Layers Panel and so Composer and so the export works as needed. But I feel it would be stupid to say if you want my plugin to work correctly you need to open python console... There must be some trigger or something to force Layers Panel to update. What is it? :)

Comment: Does it not work if you add a `print` line after your loop?

Comment: @Joseph it works only if the python console is open (or was open - once open it can be closed and the Layers Panel gets still refreshed on print command which I find strange. Anyway I need something to refresh Layers panel in standard way and not that it gets coincidentally refreshed with print into Python Console.

Comment: Maybe you can try adding this at the end of your loop: `self.iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(layer)`

Comment: What if you just remove the print statements? You could still use handy classes to debug (if that's your intention) from the QGIS API. For instance, to log a message you could write  `QgsMessageLog.instance().logMessage("My message", "My plugin")` and it would appear in the QGIS Log Messages Panel.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo my goal is to update Layers Panel. At this moment the only way I found it works is to print something int open Python Console. But I would like to find standard method for that. I might try if logging of message works too but it would be still only workaround...

Comment: @Joseph thank you. I think I have tried that one already without success but will try again just to make sure.

Comment: @Miro, no, I was giving you options to log if you definitely needed to debug, now I see you're calling print to get all working. BTW, are you developing a plugin, a Processing script, ...?

Comment: @GermánCarrillo plugin, I have updated my question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Joseph I double checked and self.iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(layer) doesn't refresh Layers Panel.

Comment: Perhaps what you actually need is to update the composer legend right before exporting the composer. You can iterate composer items and once you get the legend, call its `updateLegend()` method, like this: `from qgis.core import QgsComposerLegend`    `for item in composer.composition().items():`    `if isinstance(item, QgsComposerLegend):`    `item.updateLegend()`    `break`

Comment: @GermánCarrillo thank you, I am going to test it tomorrow, so far it works  for me through opening the Python Console and printing there, thank you for update on how to check if Python Console is open.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo Sorry to say but no success, updating Composer legend does not force Layers Panel to update.

Comment: Honestly, it's really difficult to reproduce your problem. I even developed a test plugin from scratch and always got the layer panel updated. The only issue I faced was that the composer legend wasn't refreshed in all PNGs I generated. After using the code above, all the PNGs got the legend refreshed. If you're interested in the code I ended up using, you can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/gacarrillor/a37615d0fee1d0c11628cbf5ee12f242).

Comment: @GermánCarrillo Thank you very much for all this effort. To test it I have replaced my export function by  mp.exportCompo() and all gets updated as it should. Once I will find out what is there causing the update I am going to post it as answer. Thank you again.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo I have found the line which causes the refresh in Maps Printer and wrote it here as answer, thank you very much again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer might be related to many other problems too. Thanks to the Maps Printer plugin I have figured out how to ensure things are going to be refreshed  (processed) as needed:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QCoreApplication

# This line is going to update (process) everything which might wait in cue like refreshing the layers in map in print composer
QCoreApplication.processEvents()
```

My big thanks to the developer of Maps Printer plugin (Harrissou Sant-anna / CAUE du Maine-et-Loire) who's code contains these lines which helped me to figure this out and Germán Carrillo who pointed me in the right direction.